# How to go from DataFrame to multiple Series efficiently in Dask?

Tags: dask

I'm trying to find an efficient way to transform a `DataFrame` into a bunch of persisted `Series` (columns) in Dask.

Consider a scenario where the data size is much larger than the sum of worker memory and most operations will be wrapped by *read-from-disk* / *spill-to-disk*. For algorithms which operate only on individual columns (or pairs of columns), reading-in the entire DataFrame from disk for every column operation is inefficient. In such a case, it would be nice to locally switch from a (possibly persisted) DataFrame to persisted columns instead. Implemented naively:

```py
persisted_columns = {}
for column in subset_of_columns_to_persist:
    persisted_columns[column] = df[column].persist()
```

This works, but it is very inefficient because `df[column]` will re-read the entire DataFrame `N = len(subset_of_columns_to_persist)` times from disk. Is it possible to extract and persist multiple columns individually based on a single *read-from-disk* deserialization operation?

---

Note: `len(subset_of_columns_to_persist)` is >> 1, i.e., simply projecting the DataFrame to `df[subset_of_columns_to_persist]` is not the solution I'm looking for, because it still has a significant I/O overhead over persisting individual columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can persist many collections at the same time with the `dask.persist` function.  This will share intermediates.

```
columns = [df[column] for column in df.columns]
persisted_columns = dask.persist(*columns)
d = dict(zip(df.columns, persisted_columns))
```